# The image is not spinning

Tags: html, css

I followed the explanations on this jsFiddle page http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/Ugc5g/ to spin an image on my page http://www.prezzio.net/ but it does not work: the image is not spinning.

To be clear, here is the image to spin:

[image]

Here is the original code:

```css
    .spin {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
        -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
        animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
    @keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);    transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

```html
 <img class="spin" src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="" width="120" height="120">
```

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: When I inspect your page, I see just this in CSS `@keyframes spin { 100% 
 }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit lies in your `main_style.css` line `369`.

Add these lines,

```
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

And it should spin as you expect.

Comment: These lines are present in my css but unfortunately it does not spin.

Comment: @Bronzato Inspect it.. It is not present. I added it manually and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Bronzato: I mentioned this in comment to your question. Try accessing this page http://www.prezzio.net/files/main_style.css and you'll see that those lines are not present.

Comment: @Bronzato You might have added it in your dev stage. But you might forget to clear the dev caches so it'd reload the old versions of css'es.

Comment: I don't know why but my dev platform (Weebly) seems to delete the missing css code ` { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }`

Comment: Ok finally got it working by placing my problematic css code somewhere else. Seems that Weebly removed it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, here is [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/4pud6ya6/1/) with all [`Vendor prefixes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)

```css
img {
  animation: 2s spin infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.prezzio.net/files/theme/spin.png" alt="">
```

Comment: Using `to` is no different to using `100%` which OP is already doing and the code in question does spin. The problem is that their CSS file doesn't have the required code.

Comment: You are right: the css file doesn't have the required code. It seems to have been removed (automatically) by the dev platform (Weebly)